# Сводные таблицы в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных

Как найти количество женщин проживающих в USA?
Как найти долю жителей USA, без привязки к полу, относительно всего dataframe?

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
     {'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 20, 'Country': 'USA'},
     {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 12, 'Country': 'Australia'},
     {'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'France'},
     {'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 58, 'Country': 'USA'},
     {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 79, 'Country': 'USA'},
     {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 38, 'Country': 'France'},
     {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 18, 'Country': 'Australia'},
     {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 49, 'Country': 'USA'},
     {'Sex': 'm', 'Age': 43, 'Country': 'USA'},
     {'Sex': 'f', 'Age': 60, 'Country': 'France'}
])
```

Comment: Постарайтесь оформить ваш в вопрос в соответствии с [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   Age    Country Sex
0   20        USA   m
1   12  Australia   f
2   23    Germany   m
3   58        USA   m
4   79        USA   f
5   38     Russia   f
6   18        USA   f
7   49     France   f
8   43        USA   m
9   60     Russia   f
```

> как посчитать жителей Штатов женского пола?

```
In [16]: df.loc[(df['Country']=='USA') & (df['Sex']=='f')]
Out[16]:
   Age Country Sex
4   79     USA   f
6   18     USA   f

In [17]: len(df.loc[(df['Country']=='USA') & (df['Sex']=='f')])
Out[17]: 2
```

также можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [21]: df.query("Country=='USA' and Sex=='f'")
Out[21]:
   Age Country Sex
4   79     USA   f
6   18     USA   f

In [22]: df.query("Country=='USA' and Sex=='f'").shape[0]
Out[22]: 2
```

> как посчитать долю граждан России, к примеру, без привязки к полу?

```
In [18]: df.loc[df['Country']=='Russia']
Out[18]:
   Age Country Sex
5   38  Russia   f
9   60  Russia   f

In [19]: len(df.loc[df['Country']=='Russia']) / len(df)
Out[19]: 0.2
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но как сделать это только для 'f'? К примеру если добавить страну проживания каждого объекта, как посчитать женщин из USA?

Comment: у меня беда с форматированием на sof, поэтому пардон. Если к вашему примеру добавить столбец стран проживания, то 1) как посчитать жителей Штатов женского пола? И 2) как посчитать долю граждан России, к примеру, без привязки к полу?